# Devise session timeout doesn't work if computer goes to sleep? (Rails Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

The issue I'm having is that the Devise gem is not logging out users who use the app but then lock their screens and go home for the weekend. When they return, they are still logged in even though the timeout is set for way less than that. I've changed the **config.timeout_in** in devise.rb to 1 minute just to verify that it works and it does so I assume that putting the computer to sleep must disable the countdown timer. Is there a workaround for this that is possibly already built into Devise that I might be missing?

Comment: They are logged in and what? After they click any link on the page they will get logged out.

Comment: The issue is that the logout timer seems to stop completely if the computer goes to sleep. So let's say the session is supposed to end after 95 minutes of inactivity. If the user puts their computer to sleep over the weekend, when they return on Monday, their session should be ended--so as you said, when they click on a link they get logged out. But this is not the case because the timeout countdown has basically been paused over the weekend.